# linear regression in python error

Tags: python, regression

I try to implement the code below but it return an error : 'LinearRegression' object is not.  What gets wrong? Thanks

`repair_agg.groupby('block_id').apply(clf.fit(repair_agg['t'].reshape(repair_agg['t'].shape[0],1),repair_agg['lognum']))`

repair_agg is the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The Pandas `apply()` method takes a callable function. You're passing it a scikit-learn `LinearRegression` object, which is not callable.

Comment: Your question does not have enough detail for me to answer that. But generally, you'll want to define a function that does what you want, and pass that to ``apply()``.